# How do I get passwords from the keyring in the terminal for usage in scripts?

Tags: command-line, mount, password, keyrings, luks

When you have a `LUKS` encrypted drive in your computer, `Nautilus` or `Nemo` will show it under `Devices` as a drive with a little lock on it.

When you click it, you need to enter a password. If you choose to `remember this password forever`, it gets saved to your keyring. Next boot, clicking on the drive will immediately mount it.

How do I 'immediately mount' such a drive for which the passphrase is stored in the keyring, from the terminal? I want to have an autostart script that will mount my LUKS drive when I log in. I do not want to store my passphrase in the script, I want to use the passphrase from the keyring:

If you go to `Passwords And Keys`, there's a bunch of nameless keys. In their properties you can find a description like `gvfs-luks-uuid=xxxxxxxxxxxx` and also the password for that LUKS drive. This is what Ubuntu uses.

One option I thought about is `python-gnomekeyring` but it can only get the keyname and password. I need what the GUI calls 'Technical Details' to get the password for a specific `uuid` because the keyname is always empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the only answer is through `python`, but there are two bugs that make things hard.

1. You need to **manually give your keys names** (Seahorse: Descriptions) because identifying details that other applications use are not available in the python version. I have created a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-python-desktop/+bug/1144781
2. These descriptions are empty in Seahorse in the specific case of LUKS keys, but changing the empty description *does actually change the key* name so you can look for it in python. I have created a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1144703

If you are working with scripts and keyrings, please mention that these bugs affect you too.

- [Bug 1144781 affects me too](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1144781/+affectsmetoo)
- [Bug 1144703 affects me too](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1144703/+affectsmetoo)

As for the `python` part, here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gnomekeyring as gk

keyring = 'login'
keyItems = gk.list_item_ids_sync(keyring)

for keyItem in keyItems:
    key = gk.item_get_info_sync(keyring, keyItem)
    if  key.get_display_name() == 'KeyName you are looking for':
        # Your script here using key.get_secret()
        print "Password:", key.get_secret()
```

If you know of any other way, e.g. through simple bash commands, please let us know.

## 2019 update:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import keyring
from vsgui import api

keyring = 'login'
keyname = 'key you are looking for'

# Get key
key = keyring.get_password(keyring, keyname)

# Store key
while not key:
    key = api.ask_passwd(keyname)
    if key:
        keyring.set_password('login', keyname, key)
```

Comment: A python3 example?

Comment: There is also a tool in the source archive: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-keyring/-/blob/master/pkcs11/secret-store/dump-keyring0-format.c
Also see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1155765/207933

Answer (score 44):

You can use [secret-tools](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/secret-tool.1.html) to store and retrieve the password from the keyring.

To store a new password:

```
secret-tool store --label='Password for mydrive' drive mydrive
```

I let you check in the keyring how it appears. To look it up (this command can easily be inserted in your script):

```
secret-tool lookup drive mydrive
```

Comment: Note that the secret to secret-tool is that you cannot be root to work the examples!

Comment: Isnt `secret-tools` a key-value tool? Seeing that the `--label` option is mandatory, why do I need three keys for one value? I just saved my value like this: `secret-tool store --label=my_key my_key my_key` and it works, but this is super weird

Comment: @phil294 The so-called "attribute" (key) and "value" are not arbitrary. Please RTFM.

Comment: @phil294 This page explains it: [Intro to Gnome Keyring Keyrings](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/KeyringIntro) -- *"The data inside a keyring is stored in "items". Each item has a name, such as "university proxy password" or "example.org SSH private key password", a secret, and an unlimited list of attributes. Each attribute consists of a name-value pair that is intended to serve as a hint for the applications (e.g., "user=fer", or "server=example.org"). This enables applications to find the relevant item in the keyring. All strings are UTF-8."*

Comment: @xebeche I RTM but it **does not** explain what the attributes and values are. It doesn't even have a "See also" page or any useful info for learning more. However, I found the info independently. See my comment above.

Answer (score 8):

Use [Python Keyring Lib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring)

It has a convenient CLI for use in shell scripts.

#### Installation

```
pip install keyring
```

#### Setting and getting keys

```
$ keyring set system username
Password for 'username' in 'system':
$ keyring get system username
password
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the *refined* answer I ended up with after reading here, [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/1155765/52972) and testing `lssecret`:

```
$ secret-tool lookup xdg:schema org.gnome.GVfs.Luks.Password gvfs-luks-uuid {uuid}
asupersecretpassword
```

that will get you the LUKS password for a device with a given UUID. Using libsecret v0.21.1.