# Using seahorse generated password files from command-line

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, password, security, seahorse

Seahorse (aka Passwords and Keys) is a pretty cool application for general password management. It stores the keys in `~/.local/share/keyrings/`.

*Is there some way for me to easily read/modify this database of keys from the command-line?*

Comment: My apologies.  Answer deleted.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/466717 maybe?