# Is it possible to use secret-tool to lookup existing seahorse passwords?

Tags: command-line, password, seahorse

I found this post about getting passwords from the gnome keyring from commandline ([How do I get passwords from the keyring in the terminal for usage in scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262698/how-do-i-get-passwords-from-the-keyring-in-the-terminal-for-usage-in-scripts)), and I found that secret-tool is the way to go. It's great that I can store passwords with secret-tool, but I can't seem to figure out how to lookup existing passwords that were stored using seahorse, which is what I'm really hoping to do. I don't know what attribute(s) and value(s) I would need to use to query them, and the man page is fairly vague on what these could possibly be.

Comment: Do you want to recover them as plain text? I should hope that's impossible. If it is possible, change the system you're using to store your passwords.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the point of secret-tool and seahorse. I've stored some passwords in the Login portion of seahorse (thus they are available once I login; still encrypted on disk, but decrypted using my user credentials).
That's what I gather from this example (the only one I've been able to find in my many searches) [ http://www.mankier.com/1/secret-tool#Examples ] .

Comment: by the way, its not a "seahorse password", it is the gnome-keyring where passwords are stored, and seahorse is a GUI to access this keyring.

Answer (score 25):

I made a utility, [lssecret](https://gitlab.com/GrantMoyer/lssecret), that lists all items using libsecret, including all GNOME Keyring items. It looks like libsecret automatically adds a key value pair for every item, but Seahorse doesn't show them in the GUI. Here's some example output from lssecret:

```
Collection: Login

Item:   Test Password
Secret: Tr0ub4dor&3
Key:    xdg:schema
Value:  org.gnome.keyring.Note

Item:   secret-tool item
Secret: s3cret-t00l
Key:    my key
Value:  my value
Key:    xdg:schema
Value:  org.freedesktop.Secret.Generic

Item:   Unlock password for: cueball@xkcd.com
Secret: correct horse battery staple
Key:    unique
Value:  ssh-store:/home/cueball/.ssh/id_rsa
Key:    xdg:schema
Value:  org.freedesktop.Secret.Generic

Item:   Network secret for GenericSSID/802-1x/password
Secret: S3cureW1f1Passw0rd
Key:    setting-name
Value:  802-1x
Key:    connection-uuid
Value:  6a762552-04b3-cd05-45ba-586688e0a029 
Key:    xdg:schema
Value:  org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection
Key:    setting-key
Value:  password
```

GNOME Keyring stores each keyring as a collection in the secret service. You can see the default keyring, Login, in the output. The items represent:

1. A password added to the keyring using seahorse. The description is "Test  Password" and the actual password is "Tr0ub4dor&3".
2. An item added using the command `secret-tool store --label="secret-tool item" "my key" "my value"`, then typing "s3cret-t00l" into the prompt.
3. A password for an ssh key so it can be automatically unlocked by gnome keyring. It was added using ssh-add from the command line, then checking the "Automatically unlock this key at login" box when it was first used.
4. A wifi network password added by selecting "Store the password only for this user" in the NetworkManager connection editor.

**As you can see, passwords added to a keyring using Seahorse have a key value pair of "xdg:schema" and "org.gnome.keyring.Note". You can list them all using `secret-tool search --all xdg:schema org.gnome.keyring.Note`.**

Comment: Ah, this is interesting! But then how does one uniquely identify a particular password? I don't see how to search/lookup by label, which seems odd...

Comment: There is also a tool in the source archive: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-keyring/-/blob/master/pkcs11/secret-store/dump-keyring0-format.c

Comment: Doesn't appear to work if X fails to start, which is my whole issue in the first place.  "Couldn't get secret service for unknown reason" "Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY"

Comment: That's a great looking tool. Unfortunately I'm unable to read the secrets at all, with the error `No such secret item at path: /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/13`. In fact, I get the exact same error when I try GNOME Seahorse. It seems like there's an issue in libsecret or perhaps certain distros have hardened libsecret. People are talking about some keyring issue at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/seahorse/-/issues/157 and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-keyring/-/issues/91

Answer (score 12):

Okay after investigating a little further, it looks like seahorse **doesn't assign any attributes to Stored Passwords** (I'm pretty sure secret-tool can't find a password without any attributes to lookup). The reason I believe this is the case is that, after creating one in seahorse, I look at the properties->details and there are no details (ie attributes). I've found others in seahorse, though, that have details, and I'm able to look them up in secret-tool using those attributes.

The solution, it seems, is to **create the password using secret-tool**, assigning the appropriate attributes for a unique lookup later. Since they both use gnome-keyring in the background, the new password appears in seahorse the moment you create it in secret-tool.

Gnome-keyring seems more than happy to create more than one password with the exact same label (just not the exact same attributes, it will replace it if they are exactly the same), so once you've recreated it, you can just delete the old useless one from seahorse.

```
$ secret-tool store --label=DomainPassword user sjohnson domain some.domain
Password: thisismypa$$w0rd
$ secret-tool lookup user sjohnson domain some.domain
thisismypa$$w0rd
```

The reason I initially didn't want to store a password using secret-tool was that I didn't know how to get it to be a *Login* password (available upon login) through secret-tool. It looks like, **as long as "Login" is your default keystore**, secret-tool will store it there.

Comment: Does anyone know how to use secret-tool to store / retrieve passwords from a keyring *other* than the default?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it right now and I can recover my password with these arguments:

*secret-tool lookup server "ownCloud"*

Answer (score 0):

Based on Salims answer, I build a clumsy bash script:

```bsh
outFile="keyRingExport.csv"

# Get all secrets from keyring
items=`secret-tool search --all xdg:schema org.gnome.keyring.Note`

# Clean exsisiting file
echo "">"$outFile"
currentPath="none"
currentLabel="none"
currentSecret="none"

while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line == "["* ]]; then
      # Trim Path
        currentPath=${line/\/org\/freedesktop\/secrets\/collection\//""}
  fi
  if [[ $line == "label"* ]]; then
      # Trim lable
      currentLabel=${line/label = /""}
      # CSV escape
      currentLabel="\"${currentLabel//\"/"\"\""}\""
  fi
  if [[ $line == "secret"* ]]; then
      # Trim secret
      currentSecret=${line/secret = /""}
      # CSV escape
      currentSecret="\"${currentSecret//\"/"\"\""}\""
      # write to file
      echo "$currentPath,$currentLabel,$currentSecret" >> "$outFile"

      # reset current variables
      currentPath="none"
      currentLabel="none"
      currentSecret="none"
  fi

done <<< "$items"
```