# Keyring unlock prompt with auto-login

Tags: startup, keyrings

I use autologin in Xubuntu 16.04. Because of that, my login keyring is not automatically unlocked, I know that can't be changed unless you set the password to empty.

But I would like to have a prompt each time after login, where I can enter the password (if I like to). So I guess I would need a simple terminal command, that I can set up in the startup settings that unlocks the key and displays a prompt to my GUI.

What command could I use?

Comment: sorry @Terrance, your comment does not make sense. I already said, that I won't set an empty pass  because of the risks. And its of course not necessary to do it with the login, because always a tool needs a password from gnome-keyring you get this unlock prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution. First, it looks like it is necessary to install `libsecret-tools` because there is no CLI command to access the gnome keyring using `gnome-keyring` (is that true? looks strange to me).

Then you can setup a password with:

```
secret-tool store --label=Unlocker type unlock-keyring
```

And call that password with:

```
secret-tool lookup type unlock-keyring
```

You will be prompted then, to enter the keyrings password and it will be unlocked.

Of course, you don't need to setup an extra "Unlock" password, thats a bit nonsense because its just used to force the keyring to unlock. You can also choose any of your existing passwords to unlock the keyring, but I liked it more this way.

For more infos about using `secret-tools` you can lookup this question as well: [Is it possible to use secret-tool to lookup existing seahorse passwords?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470384/is-it-possible-to-use-secret-tool-to-lookup-existing-seahorse-passwords)

***If there is another solution without installing an extra `secret-tool`, I would like to hear that!***

Comment: Thanks for the solution. (There's gotta be a better way...)

Comment: The 'other' tool is gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock