# Manage "Passwords and Keys" from the command line

Tags: command-line, password, keyrings, gnome-keyring

I am new to Ubuntu and using 18.04. I have setup remmina for RDP and I found that it is storing its passwords in "Passwords and Keys". I would like a way to update those passwords from the command line. After searching I've ended up installing:

- https://pypi.org/project/keyring/
- https://github.com/kparal/gkeyring
- `apt install libsecret-tools`

But I'm coming up empty on being able to do CRUD operations on GNOME Keyring. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Create secret with attribute `myattribute=foobar`

```
secret-tool store --label="My Label" myattribute foobar
```

Retrieve secret by attribute

```
secret-tool lookup myattribute foobar
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. I have moved to a Mac and don't have a good way to test this right now.

Comment: The thing I don't understand in this answer, given the question, is "how do I determine the right attribute names and values for the passwords stored (for example) by remmina?" (in my case it's git's git-credential-libsecret credential halper, but same problem)

Comment: Fwiw, one possible answer to this "secrets discovery" question is covered here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1155765/2238 - I was able to install g++, install libsecret-devel, and then compile/make this little c++-based utility that lists all my secrets and their attribute keys and values (and optionally the secrets themselves; seems a bit dangerous, I guess I don't really understand how secret management works on linux).

Comment: OK, I think I now understand what I was missing: To use `secret-tool` you need to know *at least one* attribute key/value pair, to be able to "search". You can find these attribute key-value pairs for any given program in the "seahorse" UI, under the "Details" section of an already-stored password.